# getting form data values as null in %fdat variable in EmbPerl

Tags: perl, apache, embperl

I am getting **NULL** form data values in `%fdat` variable in `EmbPerl` for file uploads with form property `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Here is the EmbPerl code :

```
if(( defined $fdat{file} && $fdat{file} ) && $fdat{upload} )
{
         $filename = "/tmp/sample.txt";
         open (FILE, "> $filename") || die("open failed: $!");
         while (read($fdat{file}, $buffer, 32768)) 
         {
             print FILE $buffer || die("print test: $!");
             close FILE || die("close test: $!");  
         }
}
```

And HTML Code is :

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validation();">
 <table>
  <tr>   
    <td>Select EXCEL sheet</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="file" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

I am using EmbPerl/2.3.0, CGI/3.63, Perl/5.10.1, Apache/2.2.22 and Linux OS.

Comment: and your Question is?

Comment: How do you populate `%fdat`? What is the error message you get? Can you provide a small script to pinpoint your error?

Comment: There is no error displaying but fdat value becomes null. That is the issue

Comment: @Krishnachandra Sharma I am getting NULL values in %fdat variable in EmbPerl for file uploads. That was my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

It was the issue of CGI module version. Embperl uses `CGI` module internally to process forms encoded with multipart/form-data. you can retrieve the filename (local filename, as it was on the browser side) and the information provided by the CGI.pm `uploadInfo` function. The problem was fixed by upgrading CGI version to 3.37.